# dart/Flutter: Problems with Decodeing json with utf8 decode

Tags: json, flutter, decode

I try to load a json-file to put it in a filterable/searchable Listview (search for a diagnosis with a symptom). I'm new to in programming so probably there is a better / simpler way to do this but i would like to do it this way, so it doesnt get more complicated.

I get this error if i try to use utf8.decode:

"The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'."

This is what i tried:

```
class Services {
  
  static Future<List<User>> getUsers() async {

      final response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/diff.json');
        List<User> list = parseUsers(response);
        return list;

  }

  static List<User> parseUsers(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = json.decode(utf8.decode(responseBody)).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<User>((json) => User.fromJson(json)).toList();

    }
  }
```

the User Class:

```
class User {
 String symptom;
  String diagnosis;


  User(this.symptom, this.diagnosis);

 User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
  symptom = json['symptom'];
  diagnosis = json['diagnosis'];

  }
 }
```

extract of the json file:

[
{"symptom":"Kopfschmerz","diagnosis":"Migräne, Spannungskopfschmerz"}
,
{"symptom":"Bauchschmerz","diagnosis":"Apendizitis, Infektion"}
]

Is there a simple way to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: You should also post the User class, and an example of the possible content of diff.json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dynamic json.decode(String)` the returned object can have a real type of:

- `List<dynamic>`
- `Map<String, dynamic>`

But also when the type is `List<dynamic>`, `decode` has parsed also the items in the List, so in your case (since your json has structure `[{"" : ""}]`) you just need to cast the (reified) List's type parameter with the `cast()` method.

```
static List<User> parseUsers(String responseBody) {
  //final parsed = json.decode(utf8.decode(responseBody)).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  final parsed = (json.decode(responseBody) as List<dynamic>).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed.map<User>((json) => User.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```